# No space left on device while 50gb is available

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I have a problem with my free space. macOS started to run slow, all apps reports that there is no space of device, while I have a lot.

From System Information:

```
Available:  53,51 GB (53 506 232 320 bytes)
Capacity:   238,71 GB (238 711 107 584 bytes)
```

df -h

```
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                         222Gi  172Gi   50Gi    78% 3962602 4291004677    0%   /
devfs                              181Ki  181Ki    0Bi   100%     626          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                        0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /home
map -fstab                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /Network/Servers
localhost:/FC-07iTrTX6rKeriMneLyb  222Gi  222Gi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
```

**macOS version**: Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)

**Filevault**: no

**APFS**: no (at least I didn't do anything to convert)

**First aid**: Incorrect block count, Invalid volume free block count

Tried to fix it while restarting (cmd + R)
Tried `/sbin/fsck -fy`
Tried to install mac OS while reinstalling, fails with error (can't find a folder)
Can't update to High Sierra, fails to download

Any ideas?

Comment: Try rebooting in Recovery mode and use Disk Utility to do a repair of your disk. Take a backup of your drive in advance. It sounds like you have a corrupted file system, which could in turn mean that you have a broken disk drive that needs replacement.

Comment: Can you provide the *actual* error message/report that you are seeing?

Comment: @jksoegaard doesn't help. DU fixes the errors, right after that I can't save any file

Comment: @Allan `error: exit status 1: output: write <file>: no space left on device`

Comment: @NikitaTook If you rerun the repair of the disk from DU multiple times, does it find errors again and again - or does it now say that the disk is fine after having run it once?